# Take only rows with fields MAX date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have following query:

```
SELECT cl.[Name] Client, bt.Name BottleType, SUM(csi.Amount) Amount
FROM T_Clients cl
INNER JOIN T_ClientStore cs ON cs.FK_ClientId = cl.ClientID
INNER JOIN T_ClientStoreItem csi ON csi.FK_ClientStoreId = cs.ClientStoreId
INNER JOIN T_BottleType bt ON bt.BottleTypeId = csi.FK_BootleTypeID
GROUP BY cl.[Name], bt.Name
ORDER BY cl.[Name]
```

In the `T_ClientStore` table there is column `DueDate`. I want to take only the records grouped by `cl.[Name]` **for MAX(DueDate)**. Where could i define that? Somethin like to add:

```
WHERE cs.DueDate is MAX
```

Comment: please give some sample data and all tables columns

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your existing query and based on your description, a straight-forward approach would be to just turn the join on `T_ClientStore` to a lateral join, which retrieves the latest record for the given client:

```
SELECT cl.[Name] Client, bt.Name BottleType, SUM(csi.Amount) Amount
FROM T_Clients cl
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM T_ClientStore cs 
    WHERE cs.FK_ClientId = cl.ClientID
    ORDER BY cs.DueDate DESC
) cs
INNER JOIN T_ClientStoreItem csi ON csi.FK_ClientStoreId = cs.ClientStoreId
INNER JOIN T_BottleType bt ON bt.BottleTypeId = csi.FK_BootleTypeID
GROUP BY cl.[Name], bt.Name
ORDER BY cl.[Name]
```